# How to access Microsoft One Drive with python only using username & password

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, onedrive, office365api

I'm planing to transfer the files from my linux system to Onedrive. However I implemented it using Microsoft Garph API. But I want to know if I only give username and password, How can I get the access.

For your reference my code

```
import os
import requests
params = {
          'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 
          'client_id': '',
          'refresh_token': ''
         }

response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=params)
access_token = response.json()['access_token']
new_refresh_token = response.json()['refresh_token']
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
directory='./uploads'
upload_url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username/drive/root:/fotos/HouseHistory"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root,filename)
        print("Uploading "+filename+"....")
        fileHandle = open(filepath, 'rb')
        r = requests.put(upload_url+"/"+filename+":/content", data=fileHandle, headers=header)
        fileHandle.close()
        if r.status_code == 200 or r.status_code == 201:
            #remove folder contents
            print("succeeded, removing original file...")
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, filename)) 
print("Script completed")
raise SystemExit
```

How to generate the client ID & refresh token using API if the username & password is given. In addition to that we need to  set the permission also like FileReadWrite

May I know what all changes is need in my code for generalizing the script. Only by giving username & password I need to perform all this. Currently I generated the client ID  & settled the PERMISSION here manually by

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Overview

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @MushyMiddle Can you go through it

Comment: @PeterPan Can you please go through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in your [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937785/how-to-get-clientid-of-azure-active-directory-if-username-password-in-python/61946773#61946773), we cannot use username & password to get the client ID. We should create the Azure AD app in Azure portal, get client ID from there and configure it into your project.

I notice that you are trying to use `refresh_token` as the `grant_type`. That is not correct. Refresh token is used to get a new access token. You could refer to this sample: [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token).

You should use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to do the authorization. And you will get a refresh token in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-1). But it's not what you need in your project. Because you should not use `refresh_token` as the `grant_type` here. Only when you need to refresh a new access token, the `grant_type` should be set to `refresh_token`.

Please go through the [sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my requirement is to upload files from Linux system to OneDrive only by giving their username & password

Comment: May I know how can I implement this without creating an application in active directory

Comment: @EdwardArrow Do you mean that you don't want to create an Azure AD application with code or Azure Portal? Or you want to get a client ID of an existing Azure AD app by code?

Comment: If there is a way other than AAD in which we can access and upload files from Linux to one drive then   I don't want to create AAD application

Comment: As per my requirement, I can only give username & password as input to the script.

Comment: Or is it possible to create the AAD application from code with the scope and get the client ID and access token from there when I pass Microsoft username & password

Comment: @EdwardArrow No. It's impossible. Only using username & password is not secure. We have to use AAD application. And client id is also from the AAD application. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0 to learn about the basic steps to access Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: @EdwardArrow Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to create an AAD application. But this API requires you to have registered an Azure AD app. Because to call this API, you still need to pass an Access token first.

Comment: Suppose if I generate AAD for the organization account(XYZ) then can I access the employees one drive with username and password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214390/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-edward-arrow).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access consumer onedrive accounts? or onedrive for business accounts? they are 2 different things. but either way. you need to register your app with an Azure AD. it can be one you create yourself, then just allow auth to consumers etc. but either way. if you want to authenticate an app against azure, it needs to have an App Registration. if your app only connects to consumer endpoint then you can do it with azure b2c. but yes, because azure needs to be able to identify your app before you are allowed to send it usernames and passwords.