# How to get clientID of azure active directory if username & password in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, onedrive

As the title, I need to get the client ID of the active azure directory for performing file transfer between linux & onedrive. Is there any API for this.

Comment: What do you mean `client ID`?

Comment: appID generated by AAD application

Answer (score 1):

You can't use username & password to create or get the client id.

There is no connection between user credentials and client id.

You should get the client id by [creating an Azure AD app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You can see `"appId": "631a96bc-a705-4eda-9f99-fdaf9f54f6a2",` in the [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1). `appId` is the client id.

You can also get the client id form an existing Azure AD app by [getting application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) directly.

But I don't think you need to create an Azure AD app or get an Azure AD app in your code and then use the client id. If you want to call Microsoft Graph API, you should create the Azure AD app in Azure portal and get the client id from there and configure it into your project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my requirement is to upload files from Linux system to OneDrive only by giving their username & password

Comment: Is there any way in python to implement this

Comment: @EdwardArrow As we discussed in your another post, please go through the python sample project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python.